# Simply changing a HTML5 background

Tags: css, html, background

This is probably a basic question, but I've yet to figure out the answer.

```
body {
 background: url('/images/backgrounds/nice_snow.png');
 background-size: auto;
 background-repeat:repeat;
 display: compact;
}
```

This achieves the effect I want, however, because I'm using the tag "body" (I think it's called a tag), it also uses the background behind the text in the body. I want the background behind the body (so that it appears only on either side of the body). How can I alter my code to achieve this?

Comment: Give the element containing the text a background.

Answer (score 1):

The `<body>` element is behind all other elements on the screen. It contains all of the visual elements such as `<div>`, `<p>`, and `<h1>`.

If you have text in an element ( a `<div>` element for example) nested within the `body` element,  that element has *its own* background property. You can set its background color, transparency, pattern, image, etc. in the CSS styles...

```
div {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
```

So assuming you have a 500px X 500px `<div>` with some text in it, and it is nested within the `<body>` element as such:

```
<body>
 <div>text here</div>
</body>
```

…if the `<div>` has a background-color set to #FFFFFF, a user would see a white 500px square sitting over the background image of the `<body>` as you've described in your post.